# Scraping the Reposity Pattern for Command Queries, but

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern

A little experience has taught me that the repository pattern is not for me, so I'm taking a different approach.  Wrapping substantial queries into objects and for smaller "general" queries directly accessing the data layer.

However I don't want to allow the use of the POCO data models persé and instead wrap them in my purpose built domain models.

The usual way I go about this is like so (where the domain model class takes a 'source' parameter in its internal constructor)
`DbContext.Employees.Select(x => new DomainModel.Employee(x))`

Is there any way I can wrap this up safely, such that I can perform LINQ queries to my hearts content but get back the domain model I expect without ever knowing whats going on underneath?

I thought about creating a "Domain Model `DbContext`" class which wraps the data model version and in each property do the above, but I'm not entirely sure if this would have adverse affects on my query composition.

Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I like to have a data service layer sit between the DAL and the business layer. The data service layer uses DAL and other data service classes, and returns data in DTO collections. There's just no reason to leak your schema into your business code, and you can use Linq to shape your coarse-grained result sets.

Implementation isn't painful, and it leaves you in perfect position to re-use queries, refactor and bug fix, recover from schema mistakes, all without breaking your client. It also leaves you in perfect shape to integrate cross-cutting concerns like caching, logging and exception handling.

Comment: Sorry, could you give me an example of this in code?

Answer (score -1):

Use the Repository pattern for your domain, this is its purpose. Your command queries are basically bits of a repository without the semantics. So, keep the repository for business (command) and use query objects for queries. It's pointless to reinvent the wheel but calling it otherwise.

Comment: With the repository pattern you lose the flexibility of being able to query the data source via LINQ one if the primary benefits of an ORM, instead ending up with an explosion of FindEmployeeWith/By... methods.  In a way I'm keeping the only benefit of the repository pattern in that it can be mocked. by providing my own "domain model context" that should supply business objects instead of raw data objects.  The only difference is my repositories are queryable I suppose and the reason I'm using Command Queries is to keep the code tidy when complex queries arise.

Comment: You don't lose anything and I've said you can use QUERY OBJECTS(handlers) for querying the model. Your own "domain model context" IS another name for the repository pattern. You are trying to reinvent the wheel here. And your repositories should never be queryable as it defeats the purpose. Also complex queries are NOT part of the domain, they are usually part of UI. Do yourself a favour and read about CQRS. It's better to understand solutions that are available instead of inventing your own.